# Load image file to clipboard

Tags: vba, visio

I'm looking to get an image of a Visio page into the clipboard using VBA.  I can export an image of the page using the .Export method of the Page object in question. But is there a way to load an image file to the clipboard within VBA?

Or should I just use something like VB6 and make a little command line tool that just loads a jpg or bmp file path into the clipboard using Clipboard.SetData LoadPicture( "picpath" )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `Copy` the Page using VBA, won't Visio put it on the clipboard in multiple formats, including CF_BITMAP? If you then paste it in an application that does not understand Visio, I would expect it to use the bitmap instead.

Apologies if you've tried this and it doesn't work - or if I've misunderstood the question.